# Grails Controller render view from layout folder

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I am using spring security and twitter bootstrap in my application. I have this header bar that has fields for a username and password along with a login button. When I click the login button, I make an ajax call to authenticate the user. When this returns a success, I create a second ajax call to render a different header bar. Both header bars are in the form of partial views inside my layouts folder as such:

```
-Views
    - layouts
        - partials
            - _headerBasic.gsp
            - _headerUser.gsp
        - main.gsp
    - project
```

My ajax call is done as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#LoginButton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/XXXXX/j_spring_security_check',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                j_username: $("#username").val(),
                j_password: $("#password").val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/XXXXX/layout/renderNavBarLoggedIn',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#navbar").empty();
                        $("#navbar").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(errorThrown){
                        alert('Fail!1');
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                alert('Fail!2');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And my controller is as such:

```
class LayoutController {
    def renderNavBarLoggedIn(){
        render ( view: "/views/layouts/partials/_headerUser" )
    }
}
```

I've tried instead of view to do template: "/views/layouts/partials/headerUser" but that still did not work.

So in recap, I want my second ajax call to replace my top bar with the partial view. How do I go about doing this?

Thank you for all your help.

EDIT:

It's important to note that the name of the controller has nothing to do with the name of the view folder.

Comment: The convention is for the layouts directory to be used for sitemesh layouts.  I suppose you can put whatever you like there, but using it for other things is likely to cause confusion to others later.  Also, you are rendering _headUser.  Normally GSP templates are prefixed with an underscore and not whole views.  Maybe you want “render(template:’…’)” and not “render(view:’…’)”.  That isn’t the real problem here, but you might want to look at that as a separate improvement.  I described what I think is the real problem in a separate answer.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
class LayoutController {
    def renderNavBarLoggedIn(){
        render ( view: "/layouts/partials/_headerUser" )
    }
}
```

Note that I left out the “views” portion of the path.  “views” is hte default root so if you specify “/views/…” the system is going to look for “/views/views/….”

Comment: Thanks that did it. And I changed it to template to accommodate the underscore.

Comment: I would also move it out of the layouts directory for the reason I cited in another comment.  I am glad that you got it to work.